# Selecting a string from list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, data-structures

I have a list of strings `[abc1, abc2, abc3, xyz3, xyz4]`

Out of the elements with the same string preceding the number, I need to keep just the string with the highest number in my output list. So out of `abc1`, `abc2` and `abc3`, the string `abc3` should be selected. Out of `xyz3` and `xyz4`, `xyz4` should be kept.

So the final list should contain `[abc3, xyz4]`.

I've been thinking of how this problem can be solved since the past 2 days and after unsuccessfully trying out some approaches, I am still in the dark how this can be done. I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is what you need

The first step of each item is divided into two parts, number and string

Step 2 If the aphid already exists in the dictionary, its value is compared to the current item value. If it is smaller, its value is moved to the current number.
Otherwise I save the value in the dictionary.

Finally, we turn the dictionary into a list

```
def split(items):
    biggest=dict()
    for i in items:
        string = i[:-1]
        number = int(i[-1])
        if string in biggest:
            if biggest[string]<number:
               biggest[string]=number
        else:
            biggest[string]=number
            
    return list([k+str(v) for k,v in biggest.items()])

x = ['abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'xyz3', 'xyz4']

print(split(x))
```

output :

```
['abc3', 'xyz4']
```